# Python explode function on a specific character

Tags: python, pandas, explode

I have my `dataset` called `movies` in the following way:

```
   item_id  genre
    
    1       Animation|Children's|Comedy
    2       Animation|Children's|Musical|Romance
    3       Drama
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
  item_id       genre
        
        1       Animation
        1       Children's
        1       Comedy
        2       Animation
        2       Children's
        2       Musical
        2       Romance
        3       Drama
```

Meaning I want to split it through the different genres on a new line. The code until now, however it's not working and I don't understand what's wrong:

```
movies.genre = movies.genre.str.split('|')
movies = explode(movies, ['genre'])
movies.head()
```

The error:

```
NameError: name 'explode' is not defined
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: movies = movies.explode('genre')

Comment: @YOBEN_S I tried this but nothing changes.

Comment: check your pandas version